# Reading a text file using BufferedReader and Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I need to read the first *n* lines of a text file as lines (each line may or may not contain whitespace). The remainder of the text file contains an *unknown* number *N* of tokens that are whitespace-delimited (delimiters are a mixture of space, tab, and newline characters, all to be treated identically as delimiters).

I know how to read lines using BufferedReader. I know how to read tokens using Scanner. But how do I combine these two different modes of reading for a single text file, in the above described manner?

Comment: Can you give us some code what you tried and what does not work?

Comment: I think my question is pretty clear. There is no code sample to be had aside from maybe a couple of instantiation statements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a `Scanner` for both tasks. See the [`Scanner.nextLine`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) method.

If you *really* need to use both a `BufferedReader` and a `Scanner` you could simply do it like this:

```
byte[] inputBytes = "line 1\nline 2\nline 3\ntok 1 tok 2".getBytes();
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(inputBytes));

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r);
Scanner s = new Scanner(br);

System.out.println("First line:  " + br.readLine());
System.out.println("Second line: " + br.readLine());
System.out.println("Third line:  " + br.readLine());

System.out.println("Remaining tokens:");
while (s.hasNext())
    System.out.println(s.next());
```

**Output:**

```
First line:  line 1    // from BufferedReader
Second line: line 2    // from BufferedReader
Third line:  line 3    // from BufferedReader
Remaining tokens:
tok                    // from Scanner
1                      // from Scanner
tok                    // from Scanner
2                      // from Scanner
```

Comment: I agree, combining the two increases the complexity significantly. Using Scanner.nextLine() and then splitting the String on a regex will give you elements to drop into a list in very few lines of nice, maintainable code!

Comment: I can't see where the splitting would come into play though.

Comment: +1 All these things seem so obvious now that you lay them out! Thanks.